# HTTP2, NginX but still high TTFB

Tags: ssl, nginx, http2

No matter what changes we've made TTFB is high!
Surprisingly, server side guy insists that everything is set correct and the server runs fast enough but [webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/161207_N2_3750bc868388da081af91333f701c8fe/) report didn't change at all!
After so much optimization, I can't believe it doesn't change and I started to suspect TLS, gZIP and redirections...
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the page itself takes about a second to generate. Here's a curl output ([using this to get timestamps](https://blog.josephscott.org/2011/10/14/timing-details-with-curl/)), and notice the value of `time_appconnect`

```
$ curl -w "@curl_format.txt" -so /dev/null https://jimmydance.com/
    time_namelookup:  0.004
       time_connect:  0.217
    time_appconnect:  0.921
   time_pretransfer:  0.921
      time_redirect:  0.000
 time_starttransfer:  1.348
                    ----------
         time_total:  1.352
```

This would suggest that the bottleneck is the application generating the page. Looking at the page itself, it shouldn't take so long, I would look at the framework you're using or the resources allocated to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Using @frederik-deweerdt's answer and a [breakdown of curl timing figures](https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-question-of-timing/)

- **Your server is spending nearly 1 second doing its TLS handshake** (`time_appconnect: 0.921`)
- **TTFB** is `time_starttransfer - time_appconnect (1.348 - 0.921 = 0.427)`
- **the time the server spent generating the html** is `TTFB - (time_connect - time_namelookup) (0.427 - (0.217 - 0.004)) = 0.214`

so I'd say the bottleneck isn't the app, instead it's the server's slow TLS negotiation and some latency in the network.

Have a look here for a good explanation of these curl timing figures: https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-question-of-timing/

> The diagram below shows what each of those timings refer to against a typical HTTP over TLS 1.2 connection (TLS 1.3 setup needs one less round trip):
>
> [image: curl timings variable against a typical HTTP over TLS 1.2 connection]
>
> - **time_namelookup** in this example takes a long time. To exclude DNS resolver performance from the figures, you can resolve the IP for cURL: --resolve www.zasag.mn:443:218.100.84.167. It may also be worth looking for a faster resolver :).
> - **time_connect** is the TCP three-way handshake from the client’s perspective. It ends just after the client sends the ACK - it doesn't include the time taken for that ACK to reach the server. It should be close to the round-trip time (RTT) to the server. In this example, RTT looks to be about 200 ms.
> - **time_appconnect** here is TLS setup. The client is then ready to send it’s HTTP GET request.
> - **time_starttransfer** is just before cURL reads the first byte from the network (it hasn't actually read it yet). `time_starttransfer - time_appconnect` is practically the same as Time To First Byte (TTFB) from this client - 250 ms in this example case. This includes the round trip over the network, so you might get a better guess of how long the server spent on the request by calculating TTFB - (`time_connect - time_namelookup`), so in this case, the server spent only a few milliseconds responding, the rest of the time was the network.
>     time_total is just after the client has sent the FIN connection tear down.